# Mongoose populate is populating the wrong document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a react app with MongoDB and Mongoose. I have caretakers and patients.

I'm grabbing the caretaker ID after they log in and using it to populate the "patients" associated with that caretaker. But for some reason I can't figure out why my Caretaker collection is populated with itself (Caretaker) instead of the associated patients from "Patient" collection.

Patient Model:

```
const patientSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    address2: {type: String},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    zip: {type: String, required: true},
    preferredLanguage: {type: String, required: true},
    medicalCond: {type: String, required: true},
    medication: {type: String},
    allergies: {type: String},
    notes: {type: String},
    primaryCareName: {type: String},
    primaryCareNumber: {type: String},
    contactFirstName: {type: String, required: true},
    contactLastName: {type: String, required: true},
    contactRelationship: {type: String, required: true},
    contactNumb: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Caretaker model:

```
const caretakerSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    phoneNumb: {type: String, required: true},
    local: {
         username: {type: String, unique: true},
         password: {type: String, unique: true}
     },

    patient: [{
         type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Patient"
    }]
 });
```

In the above patient key, it's populating the values of the caretaker that's logged in not patient.

Here is my code to .populate

```
findById: function(req, res) {
    db.Caretaker
        .findOne({_id: req.params.id})
        .populate("patient")
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your example you:

1. Searching on Caretaker for the _id = req.params.id
2. Queried the Patient collection for Caretaker patient
3. Creating the json

[Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Are you saying if I want to populate patients in Caretaker I need to do db.Patient instead of db.Caretaker?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking before. Updated the response